# Code block scrolls to where there is no content

Tags: discussion, code-block

I'm not sure if this is possible to fix, but I'll describe it anyway. On a question [Calculate correct values to use in layout_weight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449131/calculate-correct-values-to-use-in-layout-weight) if I press my mouse's scroll button down on the code block, I can move my mouse around and scroll to areas not actually defined by the code block.

You can see what's happening below:

[image: screenshot]

I would expect it to only scroll to areas scrollbar would be allowed to go.
I believe this just started happening after I updated to Google Chrome 14 (14.0.835.163 under Windows), so it's possibly this is a bug in Chrome (tagging as discussion for now).

Comment: I don't get vertical middle-mouse scrolling on Firefox, so I can't verify much one way or the other.

Comment: I did not get that w/ Chrome 13

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome 14

Comment: Took me a while to twig that it's a screenshot and not a real iframe in your post :)

Comment: The real bug is that there are no Easter eggs outside of the normally scrollable area.  Anyone find any secret messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a [bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89366) which has been recently fixed, and I imagine will be resolved in an upcoming stable release. I'm unable to reproduce the issue in Chrome dev.