# What's up with the infinite scroll boxes?

Tags: bug, scrolling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code block scrolls to where there is no content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106451/code-block-scrolls-to-where-there-is-no-content)

Center mouse click this scroll box and you can scroll infinitely.

I'm doing this on chrome.

```
Some looooooooong textttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
It goes this way too
```

#### Demo [here](http://goo.gl/qJtWv).

Comment: No repro, Chrome 13/Win7, but cool demonstration.

Comment: I can confirm the bug. Chrome 14/Win7